# Donut doesn't looks like Blender Guru's one

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

For an odd and unknown to me reason, my donut seems to look VERY different from Blender Guru's one, as seen in the attached images. I've done exactly everything just like in the tutorial even color matching all the colors and all but it still looks off. Only difference is that the tutorial I was following is on Blender 2.83 as I recall and I am using 3.0. Although one friend went through it with 3.0 as well and doesn't have that problem. Any suggestions? I've tried making it more pink but it also doesn't seem to be it..
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you enable a Subsurface Scattering Value? Maybe it's too low? Also try going to the bottom of the Render Properties tab and under _Color Management_, change _View Transform_ from "filmic" to "standard".

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? Andrew Price (Blender Guru) has recently completely re-recorded the tutorial for Blender 3.0. His tutorial using 3.0 is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw) whereas the 2.83 one is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4).

Comment: @JohnEason I am following the 2.83. I know that there is one for 3.0 but I decided to do the one for 2.83 'cause I liked the final result more .

Comment: In that case you may find that some of the settings are in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different contrast level.

*Properties -> Render Properties -> Color Management -> Look*